# I'm a beginner and I don't understand how my code works (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I want user to guess how many fingers are there (Math.random()), but it does not work the way I expect it to and I can't find the mistake.

This is all in a `<body>` tag:

```html
<p>How many fingers am I holding?</p>
<input type="number" id="userInput">
<button onclick="check()">Guess</button>
<p id="numberOfTries"></p>
   
<script>
    var fingers = parseInt(Math.random()*6);
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var i = 0;
    var num = document.getElementById("numberOfTries");
    function check(){
    
    if (userInput == fingers)
    {
        alert("You got it!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Try again!");
        i++;
    }
   num.innerHTML = "Number of tries: " + i;
   }
    
</script>
```

So, the way I see this: when the page loads it creates a random number (fingers), and then I just compare that number to the number in input. 
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: `userInput` and update of `num.innerHTML` should be inside `check()`.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's a good idea to use a submit button here. If you ever put this code inside a <form>, the button would submit the form and reset everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had just a small error. You only checked their input once. See I moved to the function scope and now it works.

```js
var fingers = parseInt(Math.random() * 6);
console.log(fingers);

var i = 0;
var num = document.getElementById("numberOfTries");

function check() {
  // This was in the wrong place. We need to check user input each time.
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  if (userInput == fingers) {
    alert("You got it!");
  } else {
    alert("Try again!");
    i++;
  }
  num.innerHTML = "Number of tries: " + i;
}
```

```html
<p>How many fingers am I holding?</p>
<input type="number" id="userInput">
<button onclick="check()">Guess</button>
<p id="numberOfTries"></p>
```

Comment: Yes!! That's it. I understand it now, works perfectly. Thank you very much.